# Why was Lei in the bag?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-transporter

In [*The Transporter* (2002)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0293662/) Franck transports Lei in a bag.

I have a hard time understanding why she was there in the first place. Did Bettancourt arrange for her to be abducted? If so why, since she is the daughter of the man he works with?

Comment: They had to package her in something. Bag is more sturdy than box and less airtight than suitcase.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY: I am not sure if you are making a joke or whether I had not been clear in my question :) What I mean is why is she in the bag to start with? What was the point of having here there? Was this an abduction? If so what for? Sorry if my question was not explicit enough.

Comment: It's been a while sicne I watched it but around the same time Eruope had a tad little problem with rich people having sex with underage girls and models dying. So I recieved it as "Wall Street"   ordering a women for some sexual fantasies that might involve killing her (similar to Head in the Clouds in Altered Carbon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transporter):

> While being questioned at the police station, Lai accesses Tarconi's
>   computer to find information on Bettencourt. Lai tells Frank that
>   Bettencourt is a human trafficker with 400 Chinese **(including her
>   family)** trapped in shipping containers.  Lai and Frank go to Bettencourt's office, where Bettencourt reveals that Lai's father, Kwai (Ric Young), is also a human trafficker and that they are partners.

And:

> However, Frank is saved when Lai reluctantly shoots her father.

It seems obvious that Lai's father is a human trafficker, and he is trafficking his own family.  Lai, being young and attractive, was probably sold to the highest bidder.

Comment: What is really weird for me is that her father had plans for her (he said that she would change and presumably take over his activities). Bettencourt capturing her, the daughter of his partner (whom he intended to take over) is a bold move to say the least.

Comment: Yes the motivation for the father to traffic his own daughter is not at all clear in the movie. The father even says he spent money to send her to school - why would he then put his own daughter in  a duffel bag in the back of a car? Yes he's a criminal scum but that doesn't mean he'd sell his own family.